# Can Swift protocol support generic without involve ABI changing?

Tags: swift, generics, abi

1. Why Swift use associated type in protocol, not generic? Is associated type is better than generic?
2. If we want Swift to support generic in protocol, will it bring in ABI change? why?

I just didn't found any resources on this topic.

Comment: You should read the [Generics Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md), which has a section dedicated to Generic Protocols.

Answer (score 0):

found answer in official doc, just FYI:

https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#generic-protocols